# Alter Table query in entity framework

Tags: edmx

I have a query regarding `ALTER TABLE` in ENTITY FRAMEWORK.
I want to drop the composite key of a table, edit data in it, then want to retain the primary key again.
My doubts are:

1. How this can be accomplished as i couldn't find any alter table statement in LINQ?
   (Sorry forgot to mention i am using LINQ)
2. Will edmx file will get updated on its own, when i'll drop and create the composite key through code?
   Please help.
   Thanks.

Comment: Ur welcome buddy... But  no need to thank people for editing in comments... Commenting is only for suggestions and improvements... Hope my edit helps you improve your future questions... All the best then...

Comment: please help me with my query..

Comment: I wish I could help you out here buddy but edmx is not my cup of tea...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do it...I think given that LINQ is trying to abstract the structure of the db away, that's probably not the right tool.

You must just open a connection to the database and execute ALTER TABLE statements against the raw database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..but i wanted to know that will edmx get updated automatically when i'll alter any table..??

Comment: No, you have to refresh the edmx file in Visual Studio by doing Refreshing tables

Comment: Ok..then i'll have to find some other way to accomplish my task. Thanks.